# @this.Html.DropDownList() does not select default for me

Tags: c#, razor, drop-down-menu

```
@this.Model.ActiveApplicationId
@this.Html.DropDownList("applications", new SelectList(this.Model.AllApplications, "ApplicationId", "Title", this.Model.ActiveApplicationId))
```

renders...

```
17
<select id="applications">
    <option value="16">app 16</option>
    <option value="17">app 17</option>
</select
```

There is no `selected="selected"` attr on the 2nd option, and there should be.  So, by default, since none of them are selected, the 1st one is selected.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: what are the types of `Model.ActiveApplicationId` and `AllApplications[0].ApplicationId`?

Comment: What's with all the this's?  They're superfluous, and unneeded.

Comment: @DanDaviesBrackett - both int's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the strongly typed version?  MVC does not respect the Selected value parameter of the SelectList.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, 
    new SelectList(Model.AllApplications, "ApplicationId", "Title"))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Slight tweak which made it work, `m => m.ActiveApplicationId`

Answer (score 1):

the second parameter of the DropDown Helper takes an object of type IEnumerable of SelectListItem but you passed an object of type of SelectList.

Comment: SelectList is a IEnumerable of SelectListItem